# MySQL exclusive row select

Tags: mysql

I have a table called 'survey_product' with the following structure:

```
id int(11)
order_id int(11)
product_id int(11)
pq1 varchar(2)
pq2 varchar(2)
pq3 varchar(2)
```

This table stores products ordered through the system.

And here are some data records in that table:

```
(1, 2, 20, '1', '1', 'y')
(2, 2, 21, '1', 'y', 'y')
(3, 2, 22, '1', 'y', 'n')
(4, 2, 23, '1', 'y', 'y')
(5, 2, 24, '1', 'n', 'y')
(6, 3, 20, '1', 'n', 'y')
(7, 3, 24, '1', 'n', 'y')
(8, 3, 25, '1', 'n', 'y')
(9, 4, 20, '1', 'n', 'y')
(10, 4, 21, '1', 'n', 'y')
(11, 4, 23, '1', 'n', 'y')
(12, 4, 24, '1', 'n', 'y')
```

Above we have 3 orders (order_id 2, 3 and 4).

I need to get the order_id for all orders that had product_id = 21 BUT NOT product_id = 20 (the other product_id for in the order are irrelevant - I'm just interested in 21 and 20).

Then I need to know the orders that had BOTH product_id 20 and 21 (again, the other products in the order are irrelevant).

This is the basic query to pull all the orders for a specific product right now:

```
SELECT order_id FROM survey_product 
WHERE product_id = 20
AND (pq1 = '1' OR pq1 = '2' OR pq1 = '3')
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve that?

I have tried

```
SELECT order_id FROM survey_product 
WHERE product_id IN (20) AND product_id NOT IN (21)
AND (pq1 = '1' OR pq1 = '2' OR pq1 = '3')
```

But it is excluding all the other values as well.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's usually beneficial to use JOINs instead of nested queries in such cases:

```
    SELECT sp.order_id
      FROM survey_product AS sp
 LEFT JOIN 
           (SELECT order_id FROM survey_product WHERE product_id = 20) AS sp_t
        ON sp.order_id = sp_t.order_id
     WHERE sp_t.order_id IS NULL
       AND sp.product_id = 21
       AND sp.pq1 IN ('1', '2', '3')
```

The query to get `order_id` having both 20 and 21 in `product_id` is similar: you just use
`INNER JOIN` without any check for `sp_t.order_id`. Or just leave as it is, but replace `IS NULL` with `IS NOT NULL` if you're lazy - but that'll run slower, I suppose. )

Here's an [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/646f9/7) to play with.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to produce the correct result. But is it excluding the other product_id in the the order (product_id 22, 23, 24 and 25)?

Comment: @raina77ow It seems much faster indeed. Can you point me to some books or readings that explain tips about efficient SQL like this? Or is this only "learnable" through experience?

Comment: @nadirs Experience doesn't hurt, of course, but there are some very helping books and resources. Of these I'd like to recommend the most [this wonderful site](http://use-the-index-luke.com/).

Answer (score 3):

I usually do this by using a nested query in WHERE condition:

```
SELECT order_id
FROM survey_product
WHERE product_id = 21
AND pq1 IN ('1', '2', '3')
AND order_id NOT IN (
    SELECT order_id 
    FROM survey_product
    WHERE product_id = 20)
```

Basically you find all `order_id`s from rows where `product_id = 20` and then you exclude them from the main query, i.e. you select `order_id`s from rows where `product_id = 21` but that are not in the `order_id`s resulting from the sub-query.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the idea. But each time I try to run the query like that it times out. I have about 100K rows in that table so I guess that adds just too much overhead.